# Is there a way to generate .pgf file from tikzpicture inside a tex document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I use beamer for presenation and usually prepare the pdf graph using tikzpicture inside a standalone document type tex file. Recently I found out the matplotlib plot can be saved as pgf file, and directly used in beamer through `\usepackage{pgf}`, and the result is great.

In order to maintain a consistent file base, I would like to use the tikzpicture environment to generate some pgf file to use in beamer. I tried the pgfmanual and the most related "Externalization Library" section gives no help. I tried to figure out how latex command may give rise to pgf file, again no luck.

So is there a quick and consistent way to generate pgf file from the tikz language prepared graph?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to convert high-level TikZ commands to low-level PGF commands and output the result to a file?

Comment: @Henri Menke Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: May I then ask *why* you want to do this?  What do you think is the advantage?

Comment: @HenriMenke I naively think it would compile faster ?

Comment: You might be right about that (the TikZ parser is quite expensive) but I don't think this functionality exists. If you care about performance you should use the externalisation which compiles your picture to a PDF which is then included back in.  There is no faster approach.  You find more info about that in chapter “50 Externalization Library” of [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for the advice. Good to know that there is nothing I can try for now.